# Spring @ResponseBody returning List

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

First I tried this to send back a list response (I'm using AJAX so at the done part I'm expecting the list response):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/a", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Xy> a( @RequestBody OtherClass oc, Model model) {
    ....codes
    List<Xy> objList = xyRepository.findAll();
    return objList;
}
```

Then this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/a", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ListWrapper a( @RequestBody OtherClass oc, Model model) {
    ...codes
    List<Xy> objList = xyRepository.findAll();
    ListWrapper lw = new ListWrapper();
    lw.setObjList(objList);
    return lw;
}
```

However with both of them I get the same error which is repeated many times but it is not looping forever so I can navigate in the site.

```
:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
```

Comment: You post the stack trace, but not the exception message. Could you?

Comment: the error message is missing in your stacktrace

Comment: That's all I get over and over again.

Comment: The stacktrace has at least the class of the exception thrown. You pasted just the sequence of methods that were at the stack (not the exception class, nor the exception message).

Comment: http://kickasspastes.com/12927/ Uploaded my whole console. That's the farthest I can go unfortunately. Is it possible to go beyond that?

Comment: There are still no exception details. If you copied your stack trace from IDE's console, beginning of the error message can be truncated. Can you redirect the logs to a file and post the beginning of the error description?

Comment: I have a stackoverflow error: Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a circular reference in the class returned from the repository (xy).

Set a breakpoint at BeanSerializer.157 or in any of the other locations from the stacktrace. Then you have the chance to see, which properties the serisalizer tries to serialize. From that you should be able to find the problematic property.

Once you found the problematic property you could exclude it from JSON serialization. You could do this with

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"foobar"})
```

Comment: Yes I had some one-to-many and many-to-one fields. Once I skipped those and the "handler" plus the "hibernateLazyInitializer" it started to work.